Custom YAML converts TRUE/FALSE to yes/no
I would like to create a custom YAML with the as.yaml function. Somehow it convert the TRUE/FALSE values to yes/no. Here is some reproducible code:
library(yaml)

x <- list(test = list(a = TRUE))
yaml <- as.yaml(x)
cat(yaml, sep = "\n")
#> test:
#>   a: yes

As you can see the TRUE value is now yes in the yaml. If we use "TRUE" instead of TRUE it is converted to "TRUE" but I don't want it to be in quotes. My expected output looks like this:
test:
  a: TRUE

So I was wondering if anyone knows why this happens and how to fix this?

If you use "TRUE", it is a string and has to be quoted in order to be distinguishable from a boolean value.

See this GitHub issue. Apparently, what you ask for can now be achieved using handlers. Note that this will not be necessary if you use the same package to load the YAML file again, though. In YAML 1.1 (not 1.2+ though) yes/no were specified as equivalents of true/false and the as.yaml package by default parses yes/no accordingly as booleans. So it's only an issue if you want to use the YAML file with another software which doesn't do that.

Hi @CherryDT, Thank you for your comment! Using handlers seems the way. When I use handlers = list(logical=verbatim_logical) it now converts the yes to true which is a lot better, thanks!

As mentioned by @CherryDT in the comments, we could use handlers to convert the yes/no to true/false like this:
library(yaml)

x <- list(test = list(a = TRUE))
yaml <- as.yaml(x, handlers = list(logical=verbatim_logical))
cat(yaml, sep = "\n")
#> test:
#>   a: true

Created on 2024-06-13 with reprex v2.1.0
